# Busy Beaver simple nonhalting rule

Tags: turing-machines

Regarding the busy beaver function, what's a simple rule to prove that the machine runs forever in one direction? I believe there's something about the machine not backtracking far enough before it repeats a state?

As an example, prove that this machine doesn't halt, where $A$ is the initial state, and the machine starts with an all-$0$ tape:

```
     A   B   C
   ------------
0 | 1RB 1LA 1LB
1 | 1RA 0RC   H
```

Obviously I'm looking for as general a rule as possible.

Comment: Have you tried to prove anything about that Turing Machine? (Obviously we are hoping you to have done as much work as possible.)

Comment: I edited your question to make the transition table unambiguous. Hopefully I picked the interpretation you intended.

Comment: @r.e.s: you are very kind. Don't you think the OP should do some work?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but I have done some "work" so far. I've got a program that reduces the pool of candidates to 6 for N=2 and 1044 for N=3, but there are still a lot of machines that just run off in one direction in a very simple pattern. That's what I'm trying to eliminate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique I was thinking of is explained here:

http://www.cogsci.rpi.edu/~heuveb/research/BB/status/nonhalters/simpleloop.html

Comment: dead link, does this information exist anywhere else?